# How can i make this simple thing work?

Tags: android, arduino, byte, output, communication

OK i have this code in android studio:

```
driver.setBaudRate(9600);
byte buffer[] = new byte[16];
driver.write(buffer,1000);
```

And i have this in arduino:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin4,OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop () {
  int ok = Serial.read();
if( //...... //){                        <------------- I don't know what to put here
  digitalWrite(ledPin4,HIGH);}

  }
```

Edit:
I want something like:

Android:

```
driver.setBaudRate(9600);
int ok = 1;
driver.write(1);
```

Arduino:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin4,OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop () {
  byte ok = Serial.read();
if( ok == 1){            
  digitalWrite(ledPin4,HIGH);}

  }
```

I am only alowed to use bytes[], how do i do that ?

Comment: I am only aloweed to use bytes, usb serial driver library..

Comment: Clear your question. Is not understandable.

Comment: Err... What did you write so far? What's wrong with the code you already wrote (besides in your code you should write `driver.write(ok);` instead of `driver.write(1);`)

Comment: Hmm.. that is an example.. i just need to write an byte [] on android but i can't send it on arduino..

Comment: Those guys who wanted to help me made this post a copy of another question.. but my question is how to tranfer an int not a byte[]..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
byte ok = Serial.read();
```

with

```
int ok = Serial.parseInt();
```

Note: if this code seems to be laggy try adding

```
Serial.setTimeout(20);
```

in void setup after

```
Serial.begin(9600);
```